# Android - FEATURE_NO_TITLE not working

Tags: android, dialog, titlebar

I am trying to display my about us page via layout, so I don't need any title bar. I tried:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
d.requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.show();
```

but when I click on the menu item, it force closes. when I comment the third line of the code above, it shows my layout with title bar, which I don't need.
P.S.: my activity extends ActionBarActivity, is this the reason? If yes then I need an alternative.

Comment: what context i need to pass for this dialog to appear?

Comment: Your activity context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a theme to your dialog can remove the title bar for you.

1. Add the following code in your res/values/styles.xml:

> ```
> <style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
> </style>
> ```

2. Pass the theme to your dialog:

Dialog d = new Dialog(this, R.style.NoTitleDialog);

Comment: @Saeed Jassani How crazy it is! The guy Developer110 just copy my answer and I can't believe that you choose him as the best answer!