# Style AlertDialog Submit Button and Title

Tags: java, android

I am styling my `AlertDialog`. I have successfully been able to style the background (see its blue) and the single choice items (see they are white with orange text).

Is it possible to style the `AlertDialog` title background, the footer submit button and footer background? See the image below for these areas highlighted in red. *Is it possible to make the `AlertDialog` to have rounded rectangle corners?*

As you can see I can set the title label background colour to blue but not the whole title background?

[image]

Implementation:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mActivity, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
builder.setTitle("Select");

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
        getActivity(), R.layout.choices, choices);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, myOnClickListener);


// Styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#0000ff</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">fonts/myCustomFont.ttf</item>
    </style>
</resources>


// choices.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:fontFamily="fonts/myCustomFont.ttf"
    android:textColor="@color/theme_orange"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="Text"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="7dip"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom layout (xml file) instead of this and add all your requirements there.
Then set that view to your dialog as:

```
builder.setView(R.layout.custom_view);
```

Also don't forget to remove the title as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041237/how-to-remove-title-from-custom-dialog/34041373#34041373).

Answer (score 0):

In this link I showed how to Style AlertDialog Submit Button and Title. It also shows how to customize the AletDialog. For example, how to change divider colro and etc. Please visit this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439849/5475941.

I hope it helps.